# Using R to fill an online search form and scrape the resulting data

Tags: r, web-scraping

This is my first attempt at web scraping. I am attempting to scrape data from https://tvnews.vanderbilt.edu/search. I want to be able to

1. direct R to search for a certain phrase, for instance Nixon tax, with different search options, for instance using all networks.
2. scrape all the resulting item numbers, for instance the first item number if you do a phrase search for Nixon tax is #1115273, including those that you need to click on the "LOAD MORE RESULTS" button to see.

Ultimately, I want to have a data frame that contains all the item numbers that are returned by the website regardless of the options you include or omit.

So far, I have attempted to use the rvest package as follows;

```
VDTA_session <- html_session("https://tvnews.vanderbilt.edu/search")
VDTA_search <- "https://tvnews.vanderbilt.edu/search"
VDTA_Nixon_form <- VDTA_session %>% 
 html_form() %>% 
 .[[1]] %>% 
 set_values('search[query]' = "Nixon tax",
            'search[from_date]' = "1968-08-05",
            'search[to_date]' = "2006-12-31",
            'search[reporter]' = '',
            'search[network]' = "1",
            'search[type]' = "exact",
            'search[type]' = "exact", 
            'search[sort_by]' = "relevance",
            'search[sort_by]' = "relevance",
            'search[sort_by]' = "relevance",
            'search[sort_by]' = "relevance",
            'search[include_commercials]' = "0",
            'search[include_news]'= "1",
            'search[include_intros]' = "0",
            'search[include_good_night]' = "0",
            'search[include_specials]' = "0",
            'search[include_evening_news]'= "1")


VDTA_Nixon_Result <- submit_form(VDTA_session, VDTA_Nixon_form)

read_html(VDTA_Nixon_Result) %>%
html_nodes(".result-id em") %>%
html_text() %>%
unname() %>%
as.character()
```

I am hampered by two issues.

1. I do not understand what to enter for the submit argument of the submit_form() function. I have tried "SUBMIT" and the CSS code for the submit button on https://tvnews.vanderbilt.edu/search. Neither seems to work.
2. Although the code does work without an entry for the submit argument, I seem to end up with exactly the same search page. I receive no results

I would be grateful for any help that points me to where my code is wrong. I am also aware that R might not be the best tool for this task, but it's all I can use at the moment.